# How to host a Sveltekit app on Github Pages?

Tags: git, github, svelte, sveltekit

I've been working on my biggest project for a while now and wanted to host it on Github Pages. I've never hosted anything before. I seem to be lost with the building of the app, I thought a separate folder was supposed to appear after building the app? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the output may be in the `.svelte-kit` directory. For GitHub pages, you need to use the [static adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) which can be configured to output to a different directory as well.

There is a [section in the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages) specific to GitHub pages that is important for making the site work.